# How to copy hbase table from hbase-0.94 cluster to hbase-0.98 cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have a `hbase-0.94` cluster with `hadoop-1.0.1`. We don't want to have downtime for this cluster while upgrading to `hbase-0.98` with `hadoop-2.5.1`

I have provisioned another hbase-0.98 cluster with hadoop-2.5.1 and want to copy hbase-0.94 tables to hbase-0.98. `Hbase` `CopyTable` does not seem to work for this purpose.

Please suggest a way to perform theabove task.

Answer (score 1):

These are available options, out of which you can choose.

1. You can use `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export` tool to
    export tables to HDFS and then you can use `hadoop distcp` to move data to
        another cluster. When data is place on second cluster you can use
           `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import` tool to import tables.
    Please look at http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#export.
2. Second option is to us `CopyTable` tool, please look at:
           http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#copytable
       Have a look at [pivotal](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/products/migrating-an-apache-hbase-table-between-different-clusters)
3. Third option is to enable hbase Snapshots,  create table
    snapshots, and then use `ExportSnapshot` tool to move them to second cluster.  When snapshots are on second cluster you can clone tables from snapshots. Please look: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots

> HBase Snapshots allow you to take a snapshot of a table without too
>   much impact on Region Servers. Snapshot, Clone and restore operations
>   don't involve data copying. Also, Exporting the snapshot to another
>   cluster doesn't have impact on the Region Servers

I was using 1 and 3 for moving data between clusters and I in my case 3
was better solution.

[Also, have a look at my answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560644/diffrence-between-hbase-copy-and-snapshot-command/37564996#37564996)

Comment: Your suggestion is good but it is only valid if different clusters have compatible version of hadoop and base installed. In my case, there versions aren't compatible: hadoop-1.0.1 to hadoop-2.5.1 and hbase-0.94.1 to hbase-0.98. I have already tried option 1 and 2 but it doesn't work.

Comment: The export was fast, the import is extremely slow, can I convert the exported data into HFile with the concept explained here: https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/    ?

Answer (score 0):

Run below command on source cluster, make sure you have cross cluster authentication enabled.

```
/usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable -Ddfs.nameservices=nameservice1,devnameservice -Ddfs.ha.namenodes.devnameservice=devnn1,devnn2 -Ddfs.namenode.rpc-address.devnameservice.devnn1=<destination_namenode01_host>:<destination_namenode01_port> -Ddfs.namenode.rpc-address.devnameservice.devnn2=<destination_namenode02_host>:<destination_namenode02_port> -Ddfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.devnameservice=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider -Dmapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false --peer.adr=<destination_zookeeper host>:<port>:/hbase --versions=<n> <table_name>
```